# Maximum number of possible MAST leaves

Tags: taproot, mast

According to [BIP-341](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki), the control block can have a length of 33 + 32m, for a value of m that is an integer max 128. Does it mean it's possible to construct a MAST with 128 levels, making 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 possible script combinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct.

Of course, that many leaves is intractable to construct. The reason for permitting that many levels is to permit unlikely leaves to be put in deeper levels, reducing the *average* control block size (while increasing the *worst cast* control block size).